# JpaSpecificationExecutor vs QueryDslPredicateExecutor

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to know which approach is better when to use *JpaSpecificationExecutor* and *QueryDslPredicateExecutor*?, yes we can use both of them at the same time.

using *queryDSL* will create many additional classes, is it bad or good for memory usage and performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of taste.

If you use JpaSecificationExecutor you relay on the standard JPA Criteria and Metamodel API. There the Metamodel API will create a meta model based on your mapping that you should use to be typesafe at compile time.

Where as QueryDSL is an additional framework that is not limited to JPA.

You can use it with JPA, SQL, Collections, MongoDB, Lucene and maybe more.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what i want really to know is when to use each one of them ? best practice !

Comment: As I said this is a matter of taste. I prefer QueryDSL because I don't like the Criteria API. But that's just me.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Can you say anything about performance differences, with focus to the respective implementations behind the scenes?

Comment: There is no performance difference. Both frameworks generate SQL. Performance can be improved on the DB side with indeces.